# Verify sheet name before using the excel sheet in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to verify the name of the first sheet before checking on columns and other things, but I cannot get it to work. Here is what I have tried so far. Thank you for any help.

```
 SFile = Worksheets("Macro").Range("F17").Value
 Set oWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(SFile)     

 Dim sh As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
 Set sh = oWB.Worksheets("SheetName")

    If sh.Name Like "SheetName" Then flg = True:

 If flg = True Then
        MsgBox "Sheet Name Exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet name does not exist"
        oWB.Close False
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work with this.

```
 For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "SheetName" Then
        exists = True
    End If
Next i
If Not exists Then
    MsgBox "Please select the correct File"
    bZX.Close False
    Exit Sub
End If
```